# Project Astoria

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-mobile

Anyone know the Reasoner why Microsoft put Project Astoria on hold?  It was in a Windows 10 build, but they removed it.  If it was testable by users and it wasn't effecting anything negatively, why would they still remove it?

Answer (score 3):

It was affecting a lot. The builds were slow, apps were crashing a lot..

And the worst was the "on-time" performances. (The longer you were using the build, worst were the performances) so they had to remove the Android-core in W10M. We've since huge perfs improvements since then

I know they're currently asking for iOS devs to send their apps to test the new iOS Bridge, but no news about Android

Comment: Both answers helped out, thanks to the both of you guys!

Answer (score 2):

**Reason 1 : Long time effects**

The project to run Android apps directly on Windows phone will affect Windows phone ecosystem in a long time basis. This will stop developers from making apps for windows phone since customers will be using Android apps on Windows already. Some may even think that publishing an Android app will be enough since it can run on Windows mobile. Why build 2 apps while Android can run in both?

Naturally Android apps will automatically have Universal advantage over mobile phone and tablet segment since it can run on Samsung Galaxy ( Android ) and Surface ( Windows ).

This will attract more young developers towards Android ecosystem.

**Reason 2 : Affected performance**

This will ruin the Windows phone ecosystem as the Android subsystem will consume more battery and drain more resources than native apps. Also they will not support live tiles, transparent tiles, contium, unified notification across devices, etc...

This will make Windows look like just an another Android if people start using Android apps on Windows phone.

Comment: Both answers helped out, thanks to the both of you guys!